# Cube root on ArcGIS raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

How I could extract a cube root of the multiplication of 3 rasters in raster calculator?

Eg: cuberoot (ras1 * ras2 * ras3)

Answer (score 11):

The cube root is *to the power of 1/3* so you could use something like:

```
(ras1 * ras2 * ras3) **(1/3)
```

---

Credit to [@JeffreyEvans](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8520/jeffrey-evans) for correcting the [operator for ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00p600000008000000).

Comment: I believe  that, in arcgis, you raise to a power using ** and not ^

Comment: @JeffreyEvans - Thank you for that, I'm not much of an ArcGIS user :)

Comment: There is specifics Pow function in field calculator.

Comment: @FelixP it is just my preference to use notation syntax, honestly i find all of the additional syntax cumbersome of using a function when you can just use the notation? But, thank you for pointing out that there is a function for this.