# Raster calculator syntax in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, syntaxerror

I'm trying to apply this equation through the raster calculator in ArcGIS:

[image]

I'm using this syntax:

(  (  ( (Raster) ^ 4 )  - (1-e) *  ( Sky T ^ 4 )  )  / e )  ^ 0.25

The raster calculator create a raster with no values

I'm doing something bad?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264698/cube-root-on-arcgis-raster-calculator/264700#comment420161_264700

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`**` is the [power operator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-spatial-analyst/an-overview-of-the-map-algebra-operators.htm) not `^`.

```
((((Raster) ** 4) - (1-e) * (SkyT ** 4)) / e) ** 0.25
```

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised that you can get it even to process at all.

I assume Tr, E, and Tsky are rasters. Try:

```
Power(((Power("RASNAME",4) - (1 - "RASNAME2") * Power("RASNAME3",4)) / "RASNAME2"),0.25)
```

Comment: Haha thanks, E and Tsky are not rasters, is possible to use ** as power?

Comment: give it a whirl and find out :)